# What is a good approach for testing Logstash pipelines?

Tags: logstash

We have several Logstash(es) pulling data from a queue and then inserting records to Elasticsearch.

Is there any good way of testing pipelines programmatically so we can include it as *"unit tests"* when we are creating pull requests to the pipeline repository?

Right now, we only test locally by altering where the pipeline is going to write (Elasticsearch, changed to `stdout`) and then we evaluate the record to check if the changes work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three years ago, I found the solution to my question.  It was [this fantastic project](https://github.com/magnusbaeck/logstash-filter-verifier).  This served me well for a long time.

Now, three years after I had the same problem.  But I had forgotten about [the solution](https://github.com/magnusbaeck/logstash-filter-verifier) and ended up in this very same question, to realise it was myself from the past.

To prevent in the next *three to four years* to have the same problem a third time, I am being very insisting on the answer to my problem, which is [this project](https://github.com/magnusbaeck/logstash-filter-verifier).

I am so sorry I failed you, me from the past.

Comment: You may have failed past you, but in doing so you've helped current me, and no doubt future others. So I figure that more than makes up for everything.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a whole lot out there.

One approach made possible with the new (as of LS6.x) stats API is to track the number of filter stage hits for a given set of inputs. If you have a grok-stage with a specific name, it should touch N documents for it to pass, and the downstage output that uses fields marked up by that earlier Grok state should also handle N lines. Stuff like that.